# Set text of a TextView for differant lines android

Tags: android, textview

I have a string with several spaces and i want to show that text in a textview in differant lines base on spaces of that string.How can I do that ?

```
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("test1\ntest2\ntest3\ntest4\ntest5\ntest5");
```

No matter else if you  can show me break line with

```
    </ br> or </br>.
```

Comment: is there any code which you tried yet? add here your efforts

Comment: Show what you have tried ?

Comment: Did you try adding `android:singleLine="false"` in TextView?

Comment: Show your text which you want to display in textview.

Comment: only missed this is android:singleLine="false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try :

```
String mystring="Hello How are you?";    
mytextview.setText(mystring.replace(" ", "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"\n"` to show the text in next line.

e.g `"This is firstline.\n This is second line"`

You can use setText() of textview and pass this string as a parameter.

Now, its up to you how and what you want show in textview.